# Wix: Feature Condition on Property set by Custom Action

Tags: vbscript, wix, custom-action

In my WIX setup package I have a feature that contains merge module and must be installed conditionally. The condition should be evaluated using property set by custom action. Here's how this looks in my WXS:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="testSetup">
    <Merge Id="mergeA" Language="1033" SourceFile="test.msm" DiskId="1" />
</Directory>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="find" Before="CostInitialize">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="find" Return="check" BinaryKey="script" VBScriptCall="findA" />
<Binary Id="script" SourceFile="script.vbs" />
```

Since level=0 disables the feature I've put NOT to install only if the path exists.

```
<Feature Id="productFeatA" Title="featA" Level="1">
  <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[NOT pathA]]></Condition>
  <MergeRef Id="mergeA" />
</Feature>
```

And the simple test VBS script:

```
Function findA
     Session.Property("pathA") = "test"
End Function
```

So using properties that are set via custom action I cannot get feature conditions to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom action is currently only scheduled to run in the `InstallExecuteSequence`. If your install runs through the `InstallUISequence` then the `Feature` will still get enabled. The `InstallUISequence` is unless you explicitly specify to run the install 'quietly'.

Fortunately, the fix is easy. Add the following as a peer of the `InstallExecuteSequence`:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="find" Before="CostInitialize">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```